# AppDynamics Dashboards on the TV display

Tags: gruntjs, television, appdynamics

I haven't found anywhere an answer, so I decided to write here.

Is it possible to display AppDynamics Dashboards on the TV display?
Currently I'm using something like **GRUNT** (gruntjs.com), but nowhere can I find whether it is feasible with that? Currently I'm using GRUNT for displaying tasks from Jenkins, but I don't know how to configure it with AppDynamics.

Regards,
Kamil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what the problem is, but you can share a Dashboard and open this shared Dashboard URL and make the Browser fullscreen. Thats how we do it and it works perfectly (on AppDynamics controller version 4.2).

```
Toolbar --> Dashboard & Reports --> Chose a dashboard --> 
Switch to edit mode --> Actions --> Share Dashboard --> Action (again) --> 
Open Shared URL in new window --> Make Browser fullscreen
```

We use the 'revolver tab' add-on for the browser to switch between desktops.